# Make FontAwesomeIcon center in button

Tags: react-bootstrap, react-font-awesome

I'm using react-bootstrap button and fortawesome/react-fontawesome for the icon. I'm setting the button height and width using this code

```
#button-size{
  height: 1vh;
  width: 1vw;
}
```

then I'm inserting the icon inside the button using this code

```
<Button id="button-size">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF}  />
</Button>
```

but my problem is the icon goes outside of the button. How can I center the icon inside the button

Comment: did you tried to align center text? 

`text-align:center;
line-height: 1vh;
font-size:1vh;`

Comment: @AliQorbani yes i tried but it's not working

Comment: Did my answer help? Any feedback? Please help improve Stack Overflow's content by reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Using viewport measurements for `height` and `width` on the `Button` to control its size won't work well in this setup especially when you are using font icons (also, apparently, in the library you are using they generate the output as svg). I suggest you control the size of the button through padding or pixel measurements.

Example:

```
#button-size {
  padding: 6px 20px;
}
```

In addition, If you need to adjust the size of the font icon you can do that using the `size` prop or you can use `CSS` `font-size`

```
<Button id="button-size">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} size={"5x"}/>
</Button>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-drake-5pexo?file=/src/App.js

---

If you absolutely must use the viewport measurements on your project, **which I highly discourage**, you can opt to assign `position-relative` to the button and style the font-icon component as necessary to center.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const customFontIconStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Button id="button-size" className="position-relative">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} style={customFontIconStyle} />
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
}
```